# How to call Vertex AI API from a Flutter mobile app?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-vertex-ai

How to get gcloud access token to use it
In a Flutter mobile app.
It expires in max 12 hours if generated from gcloud command line.
Thanks.

```
MODEL_ID="chat-bison"
PROJECT_ID=PROJECT_ID

curl \
-X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/${MODEL_ID}:predict -d \
'{
  "instances": [{
      "context":  "My name is Ned. You are my personal assistant. My favorite movies are Lord of the Rings and Hobbit.",
      "examples": [ {
          "input": {"content": "Who do you work for?"},
          "output": {"content": "I work for Ned."}
      },
      {
          "input": {"content": "What do I like?"},
          "output": {"content": "Ned likes watching movies."}
      }],
      "messages": [
      {
          "author": "user",
          "content": "Are my favorite movies based on a book series?",
      }]
  }],
  "parameters": {
    "temperature": 0.3,
    "maxOutputTokens": 200,
    "topP": 0.8,
    "topK": 40
  }
}
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gemini

Comment: Thanks. I saw this yesterday, but I can’t use it because it is still not available in Canada (I can’t get the key)

Comment: Not 100% sure it'll work but https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis does include an api for Vertex AI - you might be able to pass it your project-specific url.

Comment: Another way to do it would be to set up your own server (for example using firebase functions) which calls the API using a service account. That would handle app<->server authentication rather than having to manually/programatically handle access control to your GC project.

Answer (score 0):

As @rmtmckenzie mentioned in the comment:

*To solve the above issue you can consider setting up your own server (for example using firebase functions) which calls the API using a service account. That would handle app<->server authentication rather than having to manually/programmatically handle access control to your GC project.*

For more information and workaround refer to these [link1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gemini) and [link2](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis).

Posting the answer as ***community wiki*** for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.

Comment: Thanks. The solution suggested by @rmtmckenzie solved my problem.

Comment: Hi @user33629 , I am glad to hear that your issue is resolved. If you want to add more details feel free to edit my answer. You can also consider marking my answer as accepted, this will help others in their research.